# Slowness issue with DMZ Jenkins due to active directory integration

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, domaincontroller, dmz

I have DMZ Jenkins, where the active Directory login is not working for us. Our network team have noticed that request is being sent to multiple domain controllers servers (which cause us slowness in login- almost 10 minutes). how can we limit it to only one DC server?

Jenkins version: 2.176.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to mention the specific DC on the Site field